# Node.js update element in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following Mongoose schema and model:

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema({
    deviceId:String,
    deviceName:String,
    devicePlace:String,

    socket : [{number: Number,name:String, state : Boolean, current: Number, image:Number,locked:Boolean,reserved:Boolean}]
});
```

I already have a device in my database with four sockets.

Here example!

This is original data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5626569006bc3da468bafe93"),
    "deviceId" : "0013A20040B5769A",
    "deviceName" : "device",
    "devicePlace" : "place",
    "__v" : 0,
    "socket" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5628bd83570be84e28879e2d"),
            "number" : 0,
            "name" : "name"
            "state" : true,
            "current" : 0
            "image" : 0,
            "locked" : false,
            "reserved" : false,
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

and I received data from client for update.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5626569006bc3da468bafe93"),
    "deviceId" : "0013A20040B5769A",
    "__v" : 0,
    "socket" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5628bd83570be84e28879e2d"),
            "number" : 0,
            "name" : "new name!!!!!"
            "state" : true,
            "current" : 0
        }, ... 
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to update a specific socket's name in the database with the following command:

```
device.update({deviceId: newData.deviceId, "socket.number": newData.number}, {$set: {"socket.$.name": newData.name}})
```

newData is object that extracted from socket array in received data.

I want to just update first socket's name.
or if possible, I want to update every socket's name as received socket array.

But this does not seem to be working, but I get no error. Can someone pin point what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Code looks fine. What are the `newData` object values? Can you edit your question to show some sample documents?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the callback to the update statement to see the error trace.

```
     device.update({deviceId:newData.deviceId,'socket.number':newData.number}
                  ,{$set: {"socket.$.name" : newData.name}}
                  ,function(error,updatedDevice){

         if(error) throw error;
         // or : console.log("update error",error.message);
    })
```